# How can I give a specific width/responsive for the description?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can i make the description responsive, like going to the next line? It's not going to the next line instead it extends horizontally. I can easily fix this if I use textField but I need to adjust the padding and the outline of it, is there any other way?

```
     <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                <Box sx={{height: {xs: 150, md: 300}, width: '300px', border:1, padding: '20px', borderRadius: '10px', display: {xs: 'flex'}}}>
                    <Box component="img" sx={{height: '100%', width: '100%', objectFit: 'contain'}} src={singleProduct.img}/>
                </Box>
            </Grid>


            <Grid container item xs={12} md={8}>
               <Box sx={{display:'flex', flexDirection: 'column', margin:'auto'}}>
                <Typography variant="h5" sx={{fontWeight: 'bold', textTransform: 'uppercase'}}> {singleProduct.title}</Typography>  
                <Box sx={{height: '40px', width: '100%', paddingY: '40px',paddingX: '20px', display:'flex', alignItems:'center', borderBottom: 1}}>
                   <Typography variant='h3'  sx={{color: '#00c853', fontWeight: 800}}> ₱ {singleProduct.price}.00</Typography>
                </Box>

                <Grid sx={{width: 500}} container spacing={2} pt={4}>
                    <Grid item xs={4} sx={{lineHeight: 2}}>
                        <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={600} color="#757575">Seller: </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={600} color="#757575">StudentID: </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={600} color="#757575">Dept: </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={600} color="#757575">Desc: </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={8}>
                        <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={700} color="#212121">John Doe</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={700} color="#212121">{singleProduct.seller_id?.studentId}</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={700} color="#212121">{singleProduct.seller_id?.department}</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={700} color="#212121">{singleProduct.description}</Typography>
                            
                        </Grid>
                </Grid>        
</Container>
```

[image]

Comment: maybe giving some `max-width`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<Grid item xs={8} zeroMinWidth>
    <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={700} color="#212121">John Doe</Typography>
    <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={700} color="#212121">{singleProduct.seller_id?.studentId}</Typography>
    <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={700} color="#212121">{singleProduct.seller_id?.department}</Typography>
    <Typography variant="body1" fontWeight={700} color="#212121" style={{overflowWrap: 'break-word'}}>{singleProduct.description}</Typography>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding these properties to Typography'styles :

```
{
 max-width:700px;
 white-space: normal;
}
```